# My RecycleView changes color after dialog is opened

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My RecycleView change color after dialog is opened. Basically, default color is white, but after i open the dialog add some items on the `RecycleView`, the backgroud color become light grey as the pictures below.

What could it be?

[image]

[image]

**Here the xml file for the activity**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CalculatorActivity"
android:id="@+id/constraintLy">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_calculator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/divider3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider3" some code here/>


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml" >

       
    </RadioGroup>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please add your design code as well?

Comment: unfortunately, no grey color on the recycleView neither on the adapter xml file

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the .xml where your RecycleView items are drawn has grey background.
Feel free to post some blocks from .xml to verify.

Comment: It is default functionality of dialog.